# what is "Dojo Name Text Box" onremove event?

Tags: dojo, xpages, dijit.form

I have a Dojo Name Text Box "xe:djextNameTextBox" on my form. By clicking [x] it removes a name from the list. How do I check what exact name was removed or clicked without parsing all values in getComponent("myNameBox").getValue()?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the only way to handle this issue is to parse all values to get the information which name exactly was removed. I had to deal with the same problem in a previous project.

### XPage

*Set viewScope var "viewFiltersAsString":*

```
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:log('beforerenderresponse (start rendering)');
requestScope.start = new Date().getTime();
viewScope.put('viewFiltersAsString', viewController.getViewFiltersAsString());
viewController.actionSetPage();}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

*Extension Library Dojo Name List Text Box control:*

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="djFilters" multipleSeparator=","
    value="#{viewScope.viewFiltersAsString}" displayLabel="true"
    title="Hier klicken um Filter zu löschen">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker caseInsensitive="false"
            labelSeparator="~" valueListSeparator=","
            valueList="#{viewController.viewFiltersLabelsAsString}">
        </xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="${javascript:compositeData.refreshId}" execMode="partial"
        action="#{javascript:viewController.setViewFiltersAsString(@Trim(viewScope.get('viewFiltersAsString')).toString())}">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:djextListTextBox>
```

### Managed Bean "viewController"

```
/**
 * Converts all filters to a useable format for dojo List Textbox
 * @return string of filters
 */
public String getViewFiltersAsString() {
    String filtersAsString = "";
    for (ViewFilter filter : viewFilters) {
        if (filtersAsString == "") filtersAsString = filter.getKey();
        else filtersAsString += "," + filter.getKey();
    }
    return filtersAsString;
}

public void setViewFiltersAsString(String viewFiltersAsString) {
    if (viewFiltersAsString != null && !viewFiltersAsString.equals("")) {
        List<String> currentfilters = Converter.toList(",", viewFiltersAsString);

        for (ViewFilter filter : viewFilters) {
            boolean remove = true;
            for (String currentFilter : currentfilters) {
                if (filter.getKey().equals(currentFilter)) {
                    remove = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (remove) {
                // user can click only one filter at one time
                setActionViewFilter(viewFilters.removeFilter(filter));
                break;
            }
        }

    } else {
        setActionViewFilter(viewFilters.removeFilter(viewFilters.get(0)));
    }
}
```

Hint: `viewFilters` is a `java.util.List` of `ViewFilter` objects and a ViewFilter is a simple java class holding information about a filter (in your case a name)

Comment: Well, I thought there is an easiest way.. Thank you Mr. Kastenhofer